# iOS/iPhone disables auto hide address bar when overflow hidden?

Tags: ios, iphone, safari, overflow, hidden

I've been running into problems with the iPhone using the **overflow:hidden** property. Whenever I use this property, it seems that the auto hide/collapse function for the address bar on the iPhone when scrolling (down) does not work anymore (Safari iOS).

I have made a test-site to strip the necessary functions to a minimum so that I can test where the error is. However, it seems that iPhone and the overflow property do not work well together...

Here's the test-site: [link](http://www.mitchellvanbeurden.eu/test)

I'm trying to get a horizontal overflow hidden for anything beyond the width of the screen and have the ability to scroll vertically. Therefore the body and html get a **width** and **height** of **100%** and the **overflow-x:hidden** property. This works great for what I wanted to achieve. However, it seems that the auto hide/collapse function of the address bar in iOS Safari on iPhone no longer works.

If I remove the **overflow** properties from the **html, body {}** and put it only on the **body**, then this function works again, but the horizontal overflow is not clipped...

I have searched numerous places an read lots of articles, but did not find a fitting solution.

Suggested and tried solutions included adding the '**position: relative**' property to the **body**, using javascript to 'force a body scroll' (also on the test site), defining a general **overflow:hidden** but including **overflow-y:auto**, ... .

I encountered this problem on a site I'm developing where I want to use **overflow:hidden** on the body/html and use **overflow-y:scroll** on a div inside. It's sort of a one-pager website where other content 'slides in' horizontally on navigation (by adjusting the **left** property of the wrapper) - therefore the need for an **overflow-x:hidden**.

Is it not possible to use the **overflow(-x):hidden** property and maintain the address bar hide/collapse function on iPhone or am I missing something here?

Comment: Hi Mitchell, were you able to resolve the issue at all?

Comment: Hi adamj, no, I did not really resolve the issue since I couldn't find a solution. To resolve the situation I restructured my entire code so that I could avoid using the overflow property. In any new projects I also try to avoid having to use this because of apparent possible issues with mobile devices.

Comment: I encountered the same issue. I am building similar web app. If somebody found solution, please let me know asap.

Comment: In my case the following worked: I made both x and y overflow: hidden for the element that is a wrapper for elements that move outbounds (to the left and to the right) sometimes and also it's a wrapper for fixed header and a wrapper for page scrollable div (quite complex thing...). Also made the height of this wrapper element: auto. So the scroll I have is page scroll.

Comment: Thank you for the input @HappyCoder, I will try your solution on my case sometime to see it in action.